# Optical conductivity: Does higher real part mean higher losses/absorption?

Tags: absorption

My question is with regards to the relationship between optical conductivity and optical permittivity. Since the imaginary part of optical permittivity signifies losses/absorption, the real part of optical conductivity signifies losses/absorption.

Does higher real part of optical conductivity mean higher losses/absorption? If so, what is the intuition behind it? Shouldn't higher conductivity mean lower loss? 
Is there something I am missing?

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Ampere-Maxwell's equation reads $$\nabla \times \vec B=\mu (\vec j+\epsilon \frac {\partial \vec E}{\partial t})=\mu (\sigma \vec E+\epsilon \frac {\partial \vec E}{\partial t}) \tag 1$$ where $\vec j$ the conduction current density, $\sigma$ is the (real) specific conductivity, $\epsilon$ is the (real) absolute permittivity, $\mu$ is the absolute permeability. The expression in the brackets on the RHS is the sum of the conduction and displacement current density, the total current density $\vec j_{tot}$. For sinusoidal time variation  of the fields and currents $\propto \exp(-i\omega t)$ with angular frequency $\omega$, the fields and currents can be expressed as complex amplitudes (phasors) and the total complex current density can be written as $$\vec j_{tot}=\vec j-i\omega \epsilon \vec E=\sigma \vec E-i\omega \epsilon \vec E=(\sigma-i\omega \epsilon) \vec E=\sigma_c \vec E=-i\omega (\epsilon+ i \frac {\sigma}{\omega})\vec E=-i\omega \epsilon_c \vec E \tag 2$$ The last three terms representing the total current show that the total current can be viewed either as being due to a complex conductivity $$\sigma_c=\sigma-i\omega \epsilon=\sigma_r+i\sigma_i \tag 3$$ or due to a complex permittivity $$\epsilon_c=\epsilon+ i \frac {\sigma}{\omega}=\epsilon_r+i\epsilon_i \tag 4$$ were $\sigma=\sigma_r$ and $\epsilon=\epsilon_r$ are the real parts, and $\sigma_i=-\omega\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_i=\frac {\sigma}{\omega}$ the imaginary parts of the  complex conductivity and and permittivity, respectively. Thus both complex conductivity and complex permittivity describe the in-phase and out-of-phase components of the total current density, i.e., the conduction current and displacement current.

According the [Poynting Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem), the power dissipation density of an electromagnetic field (EM wave) is given by the Joule term $$W=\vec j · \vec E\tag 5$$ For a complex current and electric field, this Joule power dissipation density averaged over a cycle becomes  $$W=Re(\frac {\vec E ·\vec j^*}{2})=Re(\frac {\vec E · \sigma_c^* \vec E^*}{2})=Re(\frac {\sigma_c^* |\vec E|^2}{2})=\sigma_r\frac { |\vec E|^2}{2} \tag 6$$ where $Re$ denotes the real part operator and $^*$ the complex conjugate. See, e.g., [Simon Ramo et al.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471585513), Fields and Waves in Modern Communication Electronics, 3rd. ed., 1994, Chapter 3.13 "Poynting's Theorem for Phasors", and Appendix 4.

Thus a higher real part of the conductivity $\sigma_r$ means, indeed, higher losses and for a wave with the same frequency also a higher absorption. Only the current in phase with the electric field, and thus the (positive) real part of the conductivity, $\sigma_r$, corresponds to a power dissipation and to a wave absorption. Imaginary parts of the permittivity, and thus real parts of the conductivity, can also be caused by in-phase components due to (molecular) damping.